# Orders Api Error : "Request does not match any route"

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, api, rest-api

In my Magento 1.9, I need to access orders by calling API:

http://somesiteUrl/api/rest/orders

but the response is 404 with error:

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":404,"message":"Request does not match any route."}]}}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which HTTP method are you using?

Comment: I use GET with Authorization header (token & token secret included)

Comment: May be the problem from headers. check your response header

Comment: The header are fine i double check it with another request like /products or /stockitems, only /orders is not working

Comment: @Prasanta, in magento 1.9 are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

the problem is magestore extension override orders route with another route.

the new order endpoint is : /webpos/order/find